# sending hidden value with selected optiom

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I have a drop down select form that look like this:

```
<select id="selection">
    <option>try 1</option>
    <option>try 2</option>
    <option>try 3</option>
</select>
```

I am simply targeting these values like so:

```
var selected = $('#selection').val();
```

now how would I go about targeting a hidden value in those options rather than the value between the option tags?

something like:

```
<select id="selection">
        <option value="selected 1">try 1</option>
        <option value="selected 2">try 2</option>
        <option value="selected 3">try 3</option>
</select>
```

targeting the value?

Comment: Could you expound on your question a bit more? There is no such thing as a hidden value in a select element. Only hidden input elements.

Comment: I think you are in need of a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hidden value" that you are refering to, is actually the value attribute of the option. The one between the tags is the text of the option.

When specified the `value` attribute, the `.val()` method from JQuery will already return the correct value.

```js
var selected = $('#selection').val();
alert(selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selection">
        <option value="selected 1">try 1</option>
        <option value="selected 2">try 2</option>
        <option value="selected 3">try 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need no change at all.  The "value" of a select option is always the `value` attribute, **EXCEPT** when there isn't one defined.  When there is no "hidden value" (i.e., `value="some value"`) set in the HTML, the code will default to the text that is defined for the option.

Using your code, the value of `<option>try 1</option>` (i.e., has no `value` attribute) is "try 1", whereas, the value of `<option value="selected 1">try 1</option>` (i.e., does have a `value` attribute) is "selected 1".

In fact, the only time that you really **need** to define a `value` attribute for a select option is if you need the captured value to be different from what is displayed to the user.  For examplei, if you were coding `<option value="1">1</option>`, you don't actually need the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the value attribute then you can use your same code

```
var selected = $('#selection').val();
```

It will return you selected 1

But if you want to get the nodeValue you can use

```
var selected = $('#selection').val();
var option = $('#selection option');
var selectedValue;
for(var i=0;i<option.length;i++)
{
    if(option[i].value==selected)
    selectedValue = option[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
console.log(selectedValue)
```

It will return you try 1